# onBackPressed only dismissing ProgressDialog

Tags: android

I have realized that i have a little issue with my asynctask.  I realized that when I press the back button on an android device to dismiss my progress dialog and my asynctask, only my progress dialog is being dismissed and my asynctask still executes.  I really do not know why this is happening so I was just hoping if somebody can get me back on the right track and help me with this problem.

```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() 
    {              
        /** If user Pressed BackButton While Running Asynctask
            this will close the ASynctask. */
        if (mTask != null && mTask.getStatus() != AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED)
        {
            mTask.cancel(true);
        }          
        super.onBackPressed();
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        /** If Activity is Destroyed While Running Asynctask
            this will close the ASynctask.   */

        if (mTask != null && mTask.getStatus() != AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED)
        {
            mTask.cancel(true);
        }  

        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (pDialog != null)
        {
            if(pDialog.isShowing())
            {
                pDialog.dismiss();
            }
            super.onPause();
        }  
    }

        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            if (isCancelled()){break;}

             try {
                Intent in = getIntent();
                String searchTerm = in.getStringExtra("TAG_SEARCH");
                String query = URLEncoder.encode(searchTerm, "utf-8");
                String URL = "example.com";
                JSONParsser jParser = new JSONParsser();
                JSONObject json = jParser.readJSONFeed(URL);
                try {

                    JSONArray questions = json.getJSONObject("all").getJSONArray("questions");

                    for(int i = 0; i < questions.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject question = questions.getJSONObject(i);


                    String Subject = question.getString(TAG_QUESTION_SUBJECT);
                    String ChosenAnswer = question.getString(TAG_QUESTION_CHOSENANSWER);
                    String Content = question.getString(TAG_QUESTION_CONTENT);

                    //JSONArray Answers = question.getJSONObject(TAG_ANSWERS).getJSONArray(TAG_ANSWER);


                    //JSONObject Answer = Answers.getJSONObject(0);

                    //String Content = Answer.getString(TAG_ANSWERS_CONTENT);

                               HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                               map.put(TAG_QUESTION_SUBJECT, Subject);
                               map.put(TAG_QUESTION_CONTENT, Content);
                               map.put(TAG_QUESTION_CHOSENANSWER, ChosenAnswer);

                               questionList.add(map);

                    }


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

                return TAG_QUESTION ;           

        }
```

JSONParsser:

```
public class JSONParsser {

    InputStream is = null;
    JSONObject jObj = null;
    String json = "";
    public EditText et;

    public JSONParsser () {
    }

    public JSONObject readJSONFeed(String URL) {

        try{
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(URL);
        //request.setURI(website);
        try {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
           Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        Log.d("JSON String",json);

        return jObj;

        }finally{}

    }{
    }

}
```

Comment: So what you want, do you want to cancel the AsyncTask completely aur you want to make the progressDialog be non-cancellable on backPressed ?

Comment: @shree202 Yes, i want the AsyncTask to cancel completely and to return the user back to the main activity when the user clicks the back button

Comment: Please pay attention to formatting, helps preventing bugs too.  Don't use TABs!

Answer (score 3):

You have to implement cancelling features within the `AsyncTask`s `doInBackground` method, if you wish to cancel its execution.

After you called `cancel()` [`isCancelled()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#isCancelled%28%29) will return `true`, and *after your `doInBackground` returned* `onCancelled` is executed instead of `onPostExecute`. The Parameter will issue an interrupt on the background thread, so your long-time operations are closed. However, I'd assume you catch that somewhere?

From the [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html):

> To ensure that a task is cancelled as quickly as possible, you should
>   always check the return value of `isCancelled()` periodically from
>   `doInBackground(Object[])`, if possible (inside a loop for instance.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. I have been looking around to see how can i write this `isCancelled()` is my `doInBackGround` method but I just cant wrap my hands around it.  So do you think you can help write this code if not is there a tutorial i can refer too?

Comment: There are multiple patterns for the actual implementation, they depend on your `AsyncTask`. If you have a loop executed often, add something like `if (isCancelled()){break;}`. If you execute something interruptable, handle the [`InterruptedException`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/InterruptedException.html).

Comment: I have added my `doInBackGround` method to the question and i have added `if((isCancelled())(break;}` in that code but i wanted to see if i placed it in the proper place or if there is another code i can put there since i posted my full method

Comment: Not where I ment. What part takes long executing? Also, what's `JSONParsser`?

Comment: `JSONPasser` is a class when i use `HTTPGet` method to connect to the web service and my `doInBackGround` method is just parsing through that data... Would you like me to post the `JSONParsser` class?

Comment: sadly, `HTTPGet` will not react to the Thread's interrupt from what I searched. You'll need to 1. `abort()` from some cancelling code outside the background thread the request and 2. catch an `InterruptedException` coming from the execute method (as this will get thrown once the thing comes down).

Comment: So basically my code i have to dismiss should work all i have to do is catch an `InterruptedException`

Comment: If you already call `abort()`, that's correct, but I doubt that you do this?

Comment: I have done some research on `abort()` and I think this code is the answer to my problems `if (isCancelled) {
     try {
         uploadTask.cancel(true);
         post.abort();
     } catch (UnsupportedOperationException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
}`

Comment: what is the `isCancelled` for? Are you executing that in a loop?